# Virtual "Back Button" jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a mobile web app, I have a login/ signup page where users can choose the method they want. 
In order to reduce the refresh rate of pages I am hiding and showing objects depending on what the user clicks with jquery.

I have virtual back buttons on each of the 'pages' which hide/show the objects including the back buttons themselves, each time I need to add an extra 'page' I have to add and call the different buttons.

Is there a way I can have one button and use that depending on what elements are hidden/shown?

e.g

html

```
<div id="go_button"</div>
<div id="next_button"</div
<div id="backbutton1"</div>
<div id="backbutton2"</div>


<div id="page1"
   <p> some information here </p>
</div>

<div id="page2"
   <p> some more information here </p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#gobutton").click(function(){
     $('#backbutton1').fadeIn(250);
     $('#page1').fadeIn(250);
     $('#next_button').fadeIn(250);
});

$('#next_button').click(function(){
     $('#backbutton1').hide();
     $('#backbutton2').show();
     $('#page1').fadeOut(250);
     $('#page2').fadeIn(250);
     $('#next_button').fadeOut(250);


$("#backbutton1").click(function(){
     $('#backbutton1').fadeOut(250);
     $('#page1').fadeOut(250);
     $('#next_button').fadeOut(250);
});


etc etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

I checked the currently visible page, and based on that and what button is clicked, it would go forward or back.

```js
var
  $go = $('#go_button'),
  $next = $('#next_button'),
  $back = $('#backbutton'),
  $pages = $('div[id^=page]');

$go.click(function() {
  $next.fadeIn(250);
  $back.fadeIn(250);
  $pages.first().fadeIn(250);
});

$next.click(function() {
  var $current = $pages.filter(':visible'); // Get currently visible page

  if (!$current.is($pages.last())) { // If this is not the last page, do something
    $current
      .hide() // hide current page
      .next() // get next page
      .fadeIn(250); // fade in next page
  }
});

// Opposite of the $next.click
$back.click(function() {
  var $current = $pages.filter(':visible');

  if (!$current.is($pages.first())) {
    $current
      .hide()
      .prev()
      .fadeIn(250);
  }
});
```

```css
div[id^=page] {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: none;
}

#next_button,
#backbutton {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go_button">go</button>
<button id="next_button">next</button>
<button id="backbutton">back</button>

<div id="page1">
  <p> 1 some information here </p>
</div>
<div id="page2">
  <p> 2 some more information here </p>
</div>
<div id="page3">
  <p> 3 more information here </p>
</div>
<div id="page4">
  <p> 4 more! more! more! more!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help out! Though please check the codes you provide for syntax errors (you had incomplete tags in your html) so that it would be easier for people to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function ..

```
    function operation(name){

    if(name == "go_button"){
     //operation
    }else if(name == "next_button"){
     //do this.
    } 
 }
```

now in html

```
<div id="go_button" onclick="operation('go_button')" > </div>
<div id="next_button" onclick="operation('next_button')" ></div
```